# find prime number end with 3,9,1 or 7

Tags: java

I am trying to Write a program in java that takes an integer input from a user. The program then prints out all the primes between 1 and that number, which :
a)  end with a either a 3 or a 9; 
Sample output: 3, 13, 19, 23, 29, 43, 59 etc.
b)  contains either a 1 or a 7; 
Sample output: 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 37, 41, 47 etc.

Comment: The only prime numbers that don't end in 1, 3, 7, or 9 are 2 and 5…

Answer (score 1):

A prime number is a whole number greater than 1, whose only two whole-number factors are 1 and itself.[How to find prime number](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-1-introduction-and-school-method/).

Let the number x is prime then find n=x%10,
then check this,

```
if(n==3 || n==9)
   //print the number x
```

`
Hope this would help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
    int count;

    for(int i=50;i>=1;i--){
        count=0;
        for(int j=1;j<50;j++){
            if(i%j==0)
                count++;
         }
        if(count==2){
            if(i% 10==3 ||i %10==7 || i%10==1 ||i%10==9)
               System.out.println(i);        
           }
     }
```

Comment: I am not sure the program solves the problem. In addition create at least a complete function... either way thanks for your answer.